# invoking a method by using Reflection wont work

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection

i have a class

```
private class MyRouter
{
   public string Json {get;set;}
   public string Class { get; set; }
   public string Method { get; set; }
}
```

it has to invoke the Method from the Class by Json Arg , How can i do it by Reflection??
i did this but doesnt work any help

```
MyRouter MR = new MyRouter(){initilising the class};

Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load("Common");
Type t = assembly.GetType("Common." + MR.Class);
var x = t.GetMethod(MR.Method ).Invoke(MR.Json,null);
```

Comment: How doesn't it work? Any exception?

Comment: it says : Object does not match target type.

Comment: how can i Invoke the MEthod from the class by that Arg

Comment: mmmm aren't i the only one that see that these are Properties and not methods ? you need to use [Type].GetProperties()

Comment: @Franck from what I can tell they are the names and arguments of the class and method to invoke.

Comment: @hc-evenhuis that doesn' change  the fact that t.GetMethod() doesn't contain either Json,Class nor Method. he need to call t.GetProperties()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please see the documentation of [MethodBase.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx):

1. First parameter:

   > The object on which to invoke the method or constructor. [...]
2. Second parameter:

   > An argument list for the invoked method or constructor. [...]

This means you need an instance of your class, for example by doing the following

```
ConstructorInfo constr = t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
object myObj = constr.Invoke(new object[]{});
```

Then you can invoke your method on that instance and passing your `JSON` as argument:

```
var x = t.GetMethod(MR.Method).Invoke(myObj,MR.Json);
```

Comment: +1 and if the method is static you can supply `null` as the first argument. Also an alternative for creating an object instance you could call `Activator.CreateInstance()` (I find that to be a bit more readable)

Answer (score 1):

If the method you want to invoke is `static` you can use

```
var x = t.GetMethod(MR.Method).Invoke(null, new object[] { MR.Json });
```

if it's not `static` you need to create a new instance of the object and use that to invoke the call on. You can use

```
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
var x = t.GetMethod(MR.Method).Invoke(obj, new object[] { MR.Json });
```